# Under what conditions can the exponent product rule $a^{nm}=(a^n)^m$ be used.

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation

Under what conditions can you use the exponent product rule $a^{nm}=(a^n)^{^m}$?
For example $i=\sqrt{-1}=(-1)^{1/2}=(-1)^{2\times 1/4}=((-1)^2)^{1/4}=(1)^{1/4}=1$ 
What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The rule can be used when $a$ is real and positive. As you have noted, negative $a$ gives problems, and complex $a$ are no easier. Also, $m,n$ should be real numbers.

If $m,n$ are *integers*, then the rule holds for all complex, non-zero $a$. If $m,n$ are non-negative (but not necessarily integers), then the rule is valid for $a=0$ (I like setting $0^0=1$, but $0^0=0$ also works in this case).

Comment: non negative ? :P

Comment: @gimusi $a=0$ with $m,n$ both negative gives problems, since $0^{mn}$ is defined, while $(0^m)^n$ isn't.

Comment: Yes ok I was thinking to m,n natural numbers, but of course it is not a limitatin given here.

Comment: @gimusi Actually, if we're limited to integer exponents...

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong in your string of equalities is that:

- $i=\sqrt{-1}$ is wrong since $i$ is *one* of the square roots of $-1$ (the other one being $-i$, of course);
- $(-1)^{2\times(1/4)}=\bigl((-1)^2\bigr)^{1/4}$ is wrong because $(-1)^{2\times(1/4)}$ can be $i$ or $-i$, whereas $\bigl((-1)^2\bigr)^{1/4}$ can be one of four different numbers ($\pm1$ and $\pm i$);
- $1^{1/4}=1$ is wrong because $1^{1/4}$ can be *any* fourth root of $1$: again, $\pm1$ and $\pm i$.